# while composing docker file in ubuntu 18.04 getting error?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am  trying to compose a docker file but after running some code getting an error AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded: running `/sbin/apparmor_parser apparmor_parser -Kr /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default244049792` failed with output: AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default244049792 in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/ubuntu at line 7: Found unexpected character: ''

Comment: So, could you post the contents of /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/ubuntu? Particularly the part containing line number 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By ubuntu 18.03 do you actually mean 18.04? I wasn't aware that 18.03 was an official ubuntu version.

Also when you say `composing a docker file` what do you mean? Writing a `Dockerfile` or are you trying docker-compose? What version of docker/docker-compose are you trying to run?

It seems that you've left a blank somewhere where you shouldn't have and so the parser is finding an `''` and not the property it was expecting...

Comment: sorry its ubuntu  18.04 and docker  version 18.06.1-ce . this error is occur while trying to compose@Leon

Comment: thank you for giving the reply . after deleting the space from that file it is working perfectly.thank you once again @Leon

Comment: No problem @aswathy hope I answered all your questions! Don't forget to accept the most relevant stack overflow answer!